# AngularJS via calling to Spring boot Controller responded with thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hello i will tell you step by step,what i did,

1.I have HTML page named ManualChargesListV2.html,when page loads need to load the data in the Dropdown,so i use thymeleaf to show...

Here is @Controller Code

```
@GetMapping(value="/manualbillentry")
public ModelAndView doFetchUnitCharges(HttpSession session)
{
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    WrpSession wrpsession = new WrpSession();
    wrpsession = (WrpSession) session.getAttribute("totalObj");

    try {
        model.setViewName("ManualChargesListV2");
        List<EntSetCharges> flatBillsManualList = new ArrayList<>();
        flatBillsManualList = serbilldetails.doFetchUnitCharges(wrpsession);
        model.addObject("manuallist",flatBillsManualList);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return model;
}
```

2.The html page loads the data in dropdown perfectly,when choosing dropdown again need to hit the controller to show the data regarding selected dropdown value so i use to code like

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="chargelist">Select Charge *</label>
                                <select id="chargelist" class="form-control"
                                        ng-model="selectedcharge"
                                        ng-change="getChargeDetails(selectedcharge)">
                                    <option> Select</option>
                                    <option th:each="manualunitcharge:${manuallist}"
                                            th:value="${manualunitcharge.pkSetCharges}"
                                            th:text="${manualunitcharge.fkAssignCharges.chargeName}"></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

it will call AngularJS ng-change="getChargeDetails(selectedcharge) method,**it successfully hits the controller incl selected data.And Sends the data**

```
@GetMapping(value = "manualbillentry/showmanuallist/{chargeid}")
private ResponseMsg doFetchManualChargesList(@PathVariable("chargeid")int chargeid,HttpSession session)
{
    ResponseMsg response = new ResponseMsg();
    WrpSession wrpsession = new WrpSession();
    wrpsession = (WrpSession) session.getAttribute("totalObj");

    try {
        List<EntFlatIncome> unitChargesList = new ArrayList<>();
        unitChargesList = serbilldetails.doFetchManualChargesList(chargeid,wrpsession);
        response.setStatus("success");
        response.setDataObj(unitChargesList);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.setStatus("failed");
    }
    return response;
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('ngapppmanual', []);
app.controller('ngctrlmanual', function($scope, $http, $location) {

    $scope.ngshowchargelist = false;

    $scope.getChargeDetails = function()
    {
        var url = $location.absUrl() + "/showmanuallist/" + $scope.selectedcharge;

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

        $http.get(url, config).then(function(response)
        {

            if (response.data.status == "success")
            {
                $scope.manualresult = response.data.dataObj;
                $scope.ngshowchargelist = true;

            } else
                {
                $scope.getResultMessage = "Customer Data Error!";
                }

        },
            function(response)
            {
            $scope.getResultMessage = "Fail!";
        });

    }
});
```

3. I need to Load the Data in  in same HTML page But the issue is while responding result as incl Error code 500

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "manualbillentry/showmanuallist/1", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers.

i cant understand the issue ,please someone helpme out...

Comment: at which line does error occur? Do you hit the breakpoints inside the spring controller at all?

Comment: in Spring controller responds the data perfectly,but while receiving in Angular Part in this line --- function(response)
            {
            $scope.getResultMessage = "Fail!";
        });

Comment: This is strange, If you get 500 back, then spring controller didn't return success. Try to find where exactly does it fail on backend side, you can also try to call the endpoint just from browser (instead from the app itself) or use something like Postman.

Comment: What controller is this `@RestController` or `@Controller`? My guess is you are using `@Controller` which returns html instead of JSON which you are expecting in angularJS.

Comment: @VenuDuggireddy you are right,i changed Controller to RestController works for me..Thanks for the help..u can post as a answer.pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `@Controller` which returns html, instead you can **use `@RestController`** that returns JSON which angularJS is expecting